# sending avro(avro c) encoded data through a socket

Tags: c, sockets, avro

sending avro(avro c) encoded data through a socket
I'm trying to send an avro encoded data through a socket after converting it to byte array(using memcpy).What I have done is as given below

/*client side : client.c*/

```
avro_datum_t t_msg = avro_record(temp_schema);

avro_record_set(t_msg, "TIME", time_datum)  // encoded like this
...
...

unsigned char *temp=(unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(t_msg));
memcpy(temp,&t_msg,sizeof(t_msg));//converting to byte array
sendto(sock, &temp, strlen(temp), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));//send to socket
```

/*server side :server.c*/

```
avro_datum_t time_datum;
..
..
unsigned char *recv_data=(unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(t_msg));
avro_datum_t t_msg;
bytes_read = recvfrom(sock,recv_data,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);
memcpy(bgpmsg1,recv_data,sizeof(recv_data));
if (avro_record_get(t_msg, "TIME", &time_datum) == 0) {
        printf("\nHi...0\n");
        avro_string_get(time_datum, &p);
        fprintf(stdout, "TIME: %s  ", p)
}

//trying to decode and print message like this
```

but it's not getting anything...when I try to decode and print in clent.c itself it is getting printed.But after sending through socket it is not able to retrieve..

Answer (score 0):

The data pointed to by `temp` is not actually a string, and so you can't use string functions like `strlen` with it.

Think about what happens if one byte in the middle is zero (i.e. the string terminator `'\0'`), the functions look for that to know when a string ends, and so will stop their processing there.

On the receiving side you have another problem, and is your use of `sizeof(recv_data)`, which will always be `4` or `8` bytes depending on if you're on a 32 or 64 bit platform. The `sizeof` operator is a compile-time only operator, and for pointers it returns the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

On the receiving side you have a potentially even worse problem, which is that you tell `recvfrom` to receive up to `1024` bytes, instead of e.g. `sizeof(t_msg)`.This might cause `recvfrom` to write beyond the allocated data if `sizeof(t_msg)` is less than `1024`.

Comment: could you just tell me what I have to use instead of strlen? also How retrieve the data in receiving side?what all changes I have to make?

Comment: @HarilalOP You already *have* the size, when you allocate the memory. Use that. As for the use of `sizeof(recv_data)`, use the number of bytes you received (`bytes_read`) after checking for errors of course. Also, if you're using TCP you might actually receive *less* than asked for, so you need to receive again.

Comment: @HarilalOP I don't personally know anything about the "avro" functions or messages. I only answered based on the code presented in the original question.